# Eigen matrix multiplication slower than raw SSE

Tags: c++, performance-testing, eigen, sse

I use Eigen to calc two matrix's multiplication：
left matrix query: 1 * 128
right matrix doc: 128 * 10000
and want to get the result with matrix size 1 * 10000,
this is the performance test demo code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Eigen.h>

#include "mathlib/cos.h"
#include "eigen_timer.h"

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const uint32_t dim = 128;
    const uint32_t doc_num = 100000;
    cout << ">>>> Params:\n     vec_dim[" << dim << \
            "] vec_num[" << doc_num << "] >>>> Result:\n";

    EigenTimer timer;

    // generate matrix data
    MatrixXf query = MatrixXf::Random(1, dim);
    MatrixXf doc = MatrixXf::Random(dim, doc_num);

    timer.restart();
    // Eigen calc
    const MatrixXf& res = query * doc; // multiplication
    long time = timer.elapsed<std::chrono::nanoseconds>();
    cout << "     Eigen Time: " << time << "ns\n";

    const float* query_s = query.data();
    float* doc_s[doc_num];
    for (int i = 0; i < doc_num; i++) {
        doc_s[i] = doc.col(i).data();
    }
    // sse calc
    timer.restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < doc_num; i++) {
        float a = mathlib::inner_product_sse_full(query_s, doc_s[i], dim);
    }
    time = timer.elapsed<std::chrono::nanoseconds>();
    cout << "       SSE Time: " << time << "ns\n";
    return 0;
}
```

below is the compile flag:

```
#Preprocessor flags.
CPPFLAGS(r'-D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -DNDEBUG -DEIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE -DEIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE')
CPPFLAGS(r'-DVERSION=\"%s\"' % REPO_REVISION())

#C flags.
CFLAGS('-g -pipe -W -Wall -fPIC -msse3 -ldl -lutil -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread -finline-functions -mavx')

#C++ flags.
CXXFLAGS('-g -pipe -fPIC -O2 -std=gnu++11 -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto -ldl')
```

run result is:

```
>>>> Params:
 vec_dim[128] vec_num[100000] >>>> Result:
 Eigen Time: 21126516ns
   SSE Time: 8024619ns
```

Eigen use SSE inner, but why Eigen is twice as slow as SSE in my demo？

=====
OR:
I only want to achieve (vector * matrix)'s vector result:

- query_vec with size[1 * 128]
- 1w ad_vec wise sum size[128 * 1w]

Is there any Effective way to achieve with eigen？

Comment: Did you try doing a warm-up run to make the CPU is at full clock speed and page-faults have already happened for the new memory?  Your Eigen time of 21 milliseconds is probably long enough to hide startup effects, though, for that big a difference.

Comment: Why are you defining `EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE` in your Makefile?  Isn't that gimping Eigen for no reason?

Comment: it seems not because the CPU warm-up or memory page-faults; and also 13463339ns when I not use `EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE` in Makefile@PeterCordes

Comment: Both `-msse3` and  `-mavx`? I'm pretty sure the latter supersedes and suppresses the former. Why not `-march=native` (other than to compare SSE3 only)? What version of Eigen? AVX is only recently supported, and your flags indicate it will be used. Also, remove `-DEIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE -DEIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE`, and possibly `-O3` instead of `-O2`.

Comment: Additionally to what has been said, you should make `query` (and `res`) a `Eigen::RowVectorXf`. Otherwise, you compare GEMM vs GEMV. Also, you never allocate memory for your manual SSE result (and you don't store it, either).

Comment: The line `const MatrixXf& res = ` is wrong, you should write: `MatrixXf res =` as  `query * doc` does not return a `MatrixXf` but an expression.

Comment: My Eigen version is 3, and there are no difference between SSE3 and AVX, also `-O2` and `-O3` is the same.@AviGinsburg

Comment: On my computer, the Eigen part takes 7ms and 3.2ms if I change the type of `query` and `res` for a `RowVectorXf` (on a 2.6GHz i7).

Comment: change `const MatrixXf& res = query * doc; // multiplication` to `const RowVectorXf& res = query * doc;`, the Eigen part takes really about 7ms, though, not faster than raw SSE(also about 7ms)@ggael

Comment: btw, your matrix takes 48MB meaning that it does not fit at all within memory caches and thus any code will exhibit about the same speed, that is the speed of memory transfers. Only multi-threading can help here.

Comment: I don't think you can get measurably faster than a nested raw-SIMD-loop here (and that seems to be exactly what Eigen and your manual loop are doing now).

Comment: @AviGinsburg: That's in `CFLAGS`, but this is a C++ program.  `CXXFLAGS` doesn't include either, so presumably the Eigen code is being compiled with `-O2` for x86-64 baseline SSE2.  Also, `-march=native` to enable whatever instruction sets your CPU supports, *and tune for it* instead of still generic.  That's better than using `-mavx`.